# HTML5 Determine drop drop object

Tags: javascript, html

In this W3School example I can get lots of data about the event and the target object but how do I determine what object was dropped on to the target?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the drop function, the ID of the element you are dropping in is defined as 'data'. You can therefore write `var element = document.getElementById(data)`

Now, the element variable is the object and you can get all the information you wan't about it, pass it to another function etc.